# parsing guid representation

Tags: c#, guid

I'm using mapping by code approach and convention to generate sqllite db tables on the fly.

Id property is mapped like this using Guid.Comb algorithm.

```
Id(x => x.Id, m => m.Generator(Generators.GuidComb));
```

Tests seems to be ok except one thing, inside my db table Id property is inserted in format like this `X'0A16BBC77771594D9990A166014C54F6'`.

I'm wondering why is saved that way and not in format like `aaaef973-d8ce-4c92-95b4-3635bb2d42d5`
and how can I parse this guid representation `X'0A16BBC77771594D9990A166014C54F6'`

Thanks

UPdate:
thanks to answers bellow I tried like following

```
Guid id = Guid.ParseExact("X'0A16BBC77771594D9990A166014C54F6'", "N");
```

now I'm gettng this error

`Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).`

I don't need string representation of Guid, I want to use it as identifier when quering database like  `p = session.Get<Permission>(id);`

Comment: take off the X and single quotes when parsing the Guid.  See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate a guid using this:

```
System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N").ToUpper()
```

Which will generate a GUID in this format:

> D51A752B70E743B0BA903DE7A3FFDF91

to which you can append `X'`

```
string finalFormatted = "X'" + System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N").ToUpper();
```

Of course, adjust accordingly (duh). If you already have the GUID, just use

```
string finalFormatted = "X'" + theGuidYouAlreadyHave.ToString("N").ToUpper();
```

**Update**

I now realized you want to parse. Here it goes:

```
string yourGuidString = "X'D51A752B70E743B0BA903DE7A3FFDF91";
Guid g = Guid.ParseExact(yourGuidString.Replace("X'",""), "N");
```

Comment: Question is about _parsing_, not _creating_.

Answer (score 1):

> why is saved that way?

It's probably just storing it as a 128-bit numeric field rather than a string.  The syntax for *inserting* a guid may just not require the dashes.

> how can I parse this guid representation

Use [`Guid.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.parseexact.aspx) with the `"N"` format specifier:

```
string x = "X'0A16BBC77771594D9990A166014C54F6'";
Guid g = Guid.ParseExact(x.Substring(2,32), "N");
```